# WCF Request Compression in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, request, gzip

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to try and add GZip compression to a WCF *request* from a Silverlight 5 application. I'm also using Fiddler2 with the WCF Binary plug-in to check the headers and body of  messages (e.g. Content-Type).

I can successfully add the **compressionFormat="GZip"** property to a WinForms App.Config file which results in Binary/GZipped request messages being sent...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_IService1">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip" />
                  <httpTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/WcfService2/Service1.svc"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="CustomBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

But I can't add the same **compressionFormat="GZip"** property to a Silverlight 5 app (still VS2012).

Can anyone confirm or deny this? Any workaround?

I suspect this is because SL5 in VS2012 is still using WCF 4.0. Again, can anyone confirm or deny? Does anyone know whether WCF4.5 support will ever be added to Silverlight?

TIA

Craig

Answer (score 0):

`compressionFormat="GZip"` is Working fine for me. Most of the time, problems with WCF/SL comes from configuration mismatch between Server and client. (I had spend hours with a server configured in customBinding / binaryEncoding and a client configured in basicHttpBinding)

`compressionFormat="GZip"` have to be set on the Server side in the `web.config`.
Then you have to create ServiceReference on the Silverlight5 side, and that's all. There is no visible reference to compression in the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` file. All is done server side, and as I have have understood (i can make mistake), it's the browser who handle native gzip decompression, before passing message to the SL plugin.

PS : Inspect the wire with Fiddler to see the compression at work (it's really amazing).